# Tweepy people search and list of people returned from search in python

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get all the search results from a search by name on Twitter.

Can anyone help me how can I use tweepy to list all the users, bio, # of followers for all of the search results from a search by name in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parse_list` is a list containing all the usernames(more specifically screen names), and you can get their information and/or records by coding something like this:

```
for sname in parse_list:
    try:
        user_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = sname, tweet_mode = 'extended', lang='en', count=100, include_rts=True)
    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        print("Failed to run the command on that user, Skipping...")
        continue
#   user_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=sname, tweet_mode = 'extended', lang='en').items(20)
    print(str(count)+" "+sname)
    for t in user_tweets:
        if hasattr(t, 'retweeted_status'):
            author = t.retweeted_status.user.screen_name
        else: author = t.user.screen_name
        user_id = t.user.id
        user_name = t.user.name
        user_screenName = t.user.screen_name
        user_text = t.full_text
        #user_text = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", user_text)
        user_text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', user_text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
        user_text.replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ").replace("|"," ").replace(" | "," ").replace("?"," ")
        user_text = ' '.join(user_text.split())
        user_timestamp = t.created_at
        user_retweet = t.retweet_count
        user_favorite = t.favorite_count
        userframe = [user_id,user_name,user_screenName, author,user_text,user_timestamp,user_retweet,user_favorite]
        mega_tweet_list.append(userframe)
```

Here all the Bio you might be looking for is stored in `userframe`. If you require more/other datapoints, please consider searching "twitter Introduction to JSON object" on google and you should find types of information points of your interest.